# SQLAlchemy IntegrityError Relationship using object already in the database

Tags: orm, sqlalchemy, mapping, python-3.8, referential-integrity

This is my model, made with classical mapping, classes `A` and `B` are working accordingly

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapper, relationship

from domain.a import A
from domain.b import B
from app_extentions import metadata

a_table = sa.Table(
    'a', metadata,
    sa.Column('description', sa.String(30), primary_key=True), # I think this is important
    sa.Column('value_x', sa.Boolean()),
)

b_table = sa.Table(
    'b', metadata,
    sa.Column('id', sa.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
    sa.Column('description', sa.String(50), sa.ForeignKey(a_table.c.description), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('value_y', sa.String(20), nullable=True),    
)

mapper(A, a_table)
mapper(B, b_table, properties={
    'rel': relationship(
        A, primaryjoin=(a_table.c.description == b_table.c.description)
    ),
})
```

When I do this using pytest

```py
obj1:A = retrieve_A_object() # A is already in the DB, I get it
obj2:B = create_B_object() # this is created now, it is brand new
obj2.rel = obj1

session = get_session()
session.add(obj2)
session.commit()
```

SQLAlchemy raises an error

```
    def do_execute(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
>       cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
E       sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "a_pkey"
E       DETAIL:  Key (description)=('MY DESCRIPTION') already exists.
```

I know that it's already in the db, I want to save `B` object
How can i solve this? Why is this happening?

Comment: Could it be that `obj1` and `obj2` are in different sessions?

Comment: they are totally different objs, I am editing it to make it clearer

Comment: Not sure about the exact use case, but shouldn't you set the Foreign key on the id column of `a`. Since, it currently doesn't exists, you will need to create it - is that an option

Comment: ```A``` has the ```description``` field set, the value ```MY DESCRIPTION```

Comment: https://github.com/BugliL/SQLAlchemyError I have posted a full (not) working example here